# creating multiple threads with a unique id (threads do not overlap)

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, producer-consumer

**UPDATE**

I'm solving a producer / consumer problem, and I want to create a few producers and consumers (several threads) and I have a question how can I create several threads correctly so that one task is not performed by two threads (each thread does a different task).

**code:** I tried to do it just in a loop like here:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

    public class ProducerConsumerExample {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
                Producer producer = new Producer(blockingQueue);
                Consumer consumer = new Consumer(blockingQueue);
    
                Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
                Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
    
                producerThread.start();
                consumerThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

**output:** but it doesn't work because the threads are overlapping each other

```
Producer produced : 1619703940537
Producer produced : 1619703940537
Producer produced : 1619703940537
Producer produced : 1619703940537
consumed gets: 1619703940537
consumed gets: 1619703940537
consumed gets: 1619703940537
consumed gets: 1619703940537
Producer produced : 1619703940537
consumed gets: 1619703940537
```

Comment: Each time you loop the variables are overriden, its bad practise and incorrect to declare variables inside loops that way. The recommended way is to use an ExecutorService https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial  and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Comment: What is the missing code that prints `1619703940537`?

Comment: @DuncG I updated the content with the Producer and Consumer classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing several threads use same value of `System.currentTimeMillis()` which makes it impossible to tell what is going on. Change the token you pass into the queue to be unique PER Producer and to contain Thread name:

```
public void run() {
    int counter=0;
    while (true) {

        try {
            String token = Thread.currentThread().toString() + "#"+(counter++);
            this.blockingQueue.put(token );
            System.out.println("Producer produced nr: " + token );
        } catch (InterruptedException e ) {
            System.out.println("Producer was interrupted");
        }
        sleep();
    }
}
```

Change `Consumer.run()` to print the thread name too, and you'll see more clearly which Consumer instance is consuming each action and from which Producer:

```
System.out.println("consumer "+Thread.currentThread()+" gets: " + element);
```

This will hopefully demonstrate that these are several Producer + Consumer handlers and different permutations of Producer-Consumer sending and receiving items from the same BlockingQueue.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are **thread pools**. There are various implementations included in Java which should work out of the box. Here is a definition I've pulled off of [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-thread-pool):

> Java Thread pool represents a group of worker threads that are waiting for the job and reuse many times. In case of thread pool, a group of fixed size threads are created. A thread from the thread pool is pulled out and assigned a job by the service provider.

You can check out the following pages for more info:

https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html